# Validation Engine with jtable anonymus function item click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-validation-engine, jquery-jtable

First of all thank you very much for your atension and forgive my poor english.

I am trying to use validation engine in jtable, but I am in trouble.

this is the code on my JTable

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    //setup the jtable that will display the results
    $('#EnvelopeContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Envelope Records',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting 
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize:10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        actions: {
            listAction:   'records',
            createAction: 'create',
            updateAction: 'update',
            deleteAction: 'delete'
        },
        fields: {
            id: {
                title: 'ID',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
            shiftWork: {
                title: 'Turno',
                width: '12%',
                options: { 'M': 'Mañana', 'T': 'Tarde', 'N' : 'Noche' }
            },
            date: {
                title: 'Fecha',
                width: '15%',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            },
            amount: {
                title: 'Importe',
                width: '15%',
                inputClass: 'validate[required]'
            },
            observation: {
                title: 'Observacion',
                type: 'textarea',
                width: '40%',
                inputClass: 'validate[required]'
            }
        },
        formCreated: function (event, data) {
            data.form.validationEngine('attach', {
                binded: true
            });
        },
        formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
            return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
        },
        formClosed: function (event, data) {
            data.form.validationEngine('hide');
            data.form.validationEngine('detach');
        }
    });


    $('#LoadRecordButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#EnvelopeContainer').jtable('load', {
            shiftWork: $('#shiftWork').val()
        });
    });

    $('#LoadRecordButton').click();              

});
```

jquery 1.9.1
jquery ui 1.10.0
jtable 4.2.0

validation engine 2.2

Already replace deprecated methods (live and die) in validation engine but the problem continues.

this is the order of my units

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vehiclebusiness/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vehiclebusiness/resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/vehiclebusiness/resources/js/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" href="/vehiclebusiness/resources/js/jquery/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="/vehiclebusiness/resources/js/jquery/validationEngine/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
```

The message error is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ....................(index):84

$.jtable.formCreated  ..............................................(index):84

$.Widget._trigger .....................................jquery-ui-1.10.0.js:790

$.extend._showAddRecordForm .............................jquery.jtable.js:2240

self._addToolBarItem.click ..............................jquery.jtable.js:2067

(anonymous function) ....................................jquery.jtable.js:1048

b.event.dispatch ........................................jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

v.handle ................................................jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
```